# When the parameters in the function st_area() are empty, cnosdb will crash

Tags: database, time-series, gis

When the parameters in the function st_area() are empty, cnosdb will crash.

```
public ❯ select st_area();
error sending request for url (http://localhost:8902/api/v1/sql?tenant=cnosdb&db=public): connection closed before message completed

Caused by:
    connection closed before message completed
```

And check the cnsodb log:

```
The application panicked (crashed).
Message:  assertion failed: `(left == right)`
  left: `Null`,
 right: `Utf8`: StringArray expects DataType::Utf8
Location: /Users/bichaoxue/.cargo/registry/src/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn-df7c3c540f42cdbd/arrow-array-42.0.0/src/array/byte_array.rs:454

Backtrace omitted. Run with RUST_BACKTRACE=1 environment variable to display it.
```

Why cnosdb will crashed?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug, go to github for cnosdb and raise an issue